# How to write and transform image files from one directory to another directory using open cv?

Tags: python, opencv

I am attempting to copy and apply a horizontal transformation to all images from one of my directories (directory_a), and then write them to another (directory_b) using cv2. All images are in png format. This is my first time using open cv/cv2.

When I use the code I currently have (see below), the transformation is applied but the images are saved to the same directory. Does anyone know how to properly do this?

```py
from glob import glob
import cv2

#Flip Image horizontally and add Image to directory_b Folder

directory_a = '/content/drive/MyDrive/no_copies2/train/directory_a_images'
directory_b = '/content/drive/MyDrive/no_copies2/train/directory_b_images'

input_files = glob(os.path.join(directory_a, "*.png"))

for file in input_files:
    img = cv2.imread(file)
    horizontal_img = cv2.flip(img, 1)   
    cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(directory_b, file + '_flip_v' + '.png'), horizontal_img)
```

Comment: please untag `opencv`, it's only incidental

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`file` variable is holding the path to the whole path, try:

```py
cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(directory_b, os.path.basename(file).split(".")[0] + '_flip_v' + '.png'),
            horizontal_img)
```

Answer (score 1):

It might have to do with Google Colab. Make sure you have all directories created before running the code. I previously tried doing something similar and not setting up the directories properly in the drive came with some issues.